# NoSuchMethodError exception for backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setBolt method

Tags: java, apache-storm

When trying to run the **Getting Started with Storm** example code (https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch03-topologies):

```
> storm jar target/Topologies-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar countword.TopologyMain src/main/resources/words.txt
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setBolt(Ljava/lang/String;Lbacktype/storm/topology/IRichBolt;Ljava/lang/Integer;)Lbacktype/storm/topology/BoltDeclarer;
    at countword.TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:23)
```

I have checked the method signature, and all seems correct.  Any insight into the issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: have you checked version of jar you using has that class?

Comment: I am using storm v. 0.9.0.1, and was referring to this reference (http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/topology/TopologyBuilder.html), when checking parameters.  Judging from line 138 of this code base (https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/topology/TopologyBuilder.java), it seems that documentation is not out of date.

Comment: ok.  i don't have time to verify this now, but the current git state (as of the timestamp on this comment) of incubator-storm resolves the issue.  if someone also verifies that the method attempted does not work with v0.9.0.1, but does with the current incubator-storm, and submits as the answer to this thread, i'll happily mark as the answer.  if so, i can't believe the method went from working prior to v0.9.0.1, then not working, and now working again.  since unlikely, i doubt my understanding of my observation.  though until reinforced, the info may be useful to someone else.

Comment: @ant: Can you post the maven coordinates of the incubating storm that you mention? I am not sure which version of maven you mean. I have the same issue and need to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

from your pom file i can see that you are using strom version `0.7.1`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1</version>
```

that has method signature

```
public BoltDeclarer setBolt(String id, IBasicBolt bolt, Integer parallelism_hint);
```

change that version to the `0.9.0.1` and you will be able to run that

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setBolt(Ljava/lang/String;Lbacktype/storm/topology/IRichBolt;Ljava/lang/Integer;)Lbacktype/storm/topology/BoltDeclarer;
 at countword.TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:23)
ubuntu@ip-10-250-45-151:~/gettingStartedWithStorm/ch03$ tail pom.xml 

        <!-- Storm Dependency -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>storm</groupId>
          <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.0.1</version>
       </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: it means at runtime it is getting the reference of a storm jar which has no such method. did you build the snapshot after updating pom?

Comment: my apologies, but when you say snapshot, do you mean the example code I'm trying to run?  if so, i (think i) rebuilt the code with the command, mvn compile, and, mvn package.

Comment: well here i see another possibility as well, what is the release are you using for running the code?

Comment: storm: 0.9.0.1, example code: current (last update 2 years ago) repo, mvn: 3.0.4

Comment: just to get it clarified, you downloaded the jar for storm from http://storm.incubator.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52252/discussion-between-vd-and-ant)

Answer (score 0):

After you update the pom with storm version 0.9.0.1, you will need to to a `mvn clean install` and then a `mvn package` to update the jar that you send to the cluster.